# Apache CXF REST Service with byte range parameters / MessageContext

Tags: spring, rest, cxf

Ok, somehow I feel stupid, there must be something obvious I'm missing...

I'm using Apache CXF (2.7.x) for a restful service which contains a method to retrieve some video-data. Some clients need to be able to do requests with byte ranges. First thing I need to know is the byte range that the client actually requests, so I thought I'd take a look in the http headers. 
As far as I understood all I should need to do to be able to do that is put the MessageContext as a resource in my service class:

```
@Resource
MessageContext ctx;
```

Problem is, this fails because there is no such bean:

```
Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext] found for dependency
```

In my spring config I have these includes:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

Somewhere I read that cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml is no longer needed, and as far as I know, this file doesn't even exist anywhere in my dependencies.

So what am I missing here?
Or is there another approach to support byte range requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it with

```
MessageContext ctx = new MessageContextImpl(PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage());
```

I'm not sure if that's a good solution, but it works.